# Passing JSON payload over the command line

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, powershell

I am trying to pass JSON Payload vai command line to node.js to execute the code. Its seems, Command line does not treat JSON Object as single string.

Here is the code: I have tried both Encoded and decoded JSON object but still no luck. How Can I decode JSON back to original in node js program.

```
var account_id= "109443356002";
var change_request= "chg0123456";


//Request Body Output: {"account_id":"109443356002","change_request":"chg0123456"}

//Decoded Outout: "{\"account_id\":\"109443356002\",\"change_request\":\"chg0123456\"}"

var command = C:\Users\kp250041\desktop\myfiles decoded

var requestBody = {};
requestBody.change_request = change_request+'';
requestBody.customer_id = customer_id+;


requestBody1 = JSON.stringify(new global.JSON().encode(requestBody));
var decoded = new global.JSON().decode(requestBody1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided you pass actual valid JSON to the command line and quote it correctly, you can parse the value with the [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

> The JSON.parse() method parses a JSON string, constructing the
>   JavaScript value or object described by the string. An optional
>   reviver function can be provided to perform a transformation on the
>   resulting object before it is returned.

Example:

```
data = JSON.parse(process.argv[2] || '{}')
console.log(data)
```

Then call it:

```
node test.js '{"account_id":"109443356002","change_request":"chg0123456"}'
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.

Comment: @KiranPatil if I helped you, please accept my answer as the right one :).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Still not able to convert "{\"account_id\":\"109443356002\",\"change_request\":\"chg0123456\"}" into {"account_id":"109443356002","change_request":"chg0123456"} once command is excuted.

Comment: node test.js "{\"account_id\":\"109443356002\",\"change_request\":\"chg0123456\"}" worked for me and parsed it with above command.